# Why always a0: is attached to all tags in selenium pagesource

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used selenium webdriver in java for getting the pagesource of the url https://www.kapanlagi.com/ so that i can automate some actions on top of the webpage. Unfortunately when i used driver.getPageSource(); i could get the source code but it has a0: attached to all the tags as shown below. A sample of source code is given below:

```
<a0:meta charset="utf-8" />
<a0:meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Cache-Control" />
<a0:meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma" />
<a0:meta content="Tue, 22 Jan 2013 02:30:01 GMT" http-equiv="Expires" />
<a0:meta content="900" http-equiv="Refresh" />
<a0:meta content="KapanLagi.com, situs entertainment terbesar di Indonesia. Berita, gosip, resensi film &amp; musik, foto, game, kartu ucapan, dan banyak lagi. Kalau bukan sekarang, Kapan Lagi?" name="description" />
<a0:meta content="berita, infotainment, gossip, gosip, artis, artis indonesia, indonesia, game, entertainment, film, bioskop, resensi, musik, zodiac, kartu ucapan, kartu, kartu lebaran" name="keywords" />
<a0:meta content="1048538409" property="fb:admins" />
<a0:meta content="166048096750307" property="fb:app_id" />

<a0:link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
<a0:link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/favicon.ico" />
<a0:link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/" rel="dns-prefetch" />
<a0:link href="/feed/entertainment.xml" title="KapanLagi.com Atom Feed" type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" />
<a0:link href="https://m.kapanlagi.com/" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" rel="alternate" />  
<a0:link href="https://www.kapanlagi.com/" rel="canonical" />
<a0:link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<a0:link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<a0:link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<a0:link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />    
<a0:link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<a0:title>Kalau Bukan Sekarang, Kapan Lagi? - KapanLagi.com</a0:title>
```

Comment: can we get desired source code without a0: text with selenium 2.53?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havn't mentioned the versions of the binaries you are using, but using *Selenium Java* client *v3.9.1*, *GeckoDriver v0.19.1* and *Firefox Quantum v58.0.2 (64-bit)* I am able to see a proper *PageSource* without any prefix of `a0:` as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.kapanlagi.com/");
  System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
   1520062739574  geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
   1520062739607  geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:12306
   1520062740588  mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.R5Wv9lx9f5K5"
   1520062744680  Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
   1520062762429  Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2481
   1520062763089  Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
   Mar 03, 2018 1:09:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
   <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" class="firefox" lang="en"><head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 22 Jan 2013 02:30:01 GMT">
      <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="900">
      <meta name="description" content="KapanLagi.com, situs entertainment terbesar di Indonesia. Berita, gosip, resensi film &amp; musik, foto, game, kartu ucapan, dan banyak lagi. Kalau bukan sekarang, Kapan Lagi?">
      <meta name="keywords" content="berita, infotainment, gossip, gosip, artis, artis indonesia, indonesia, game, entertainment, film, bioskop, resensi, musik, zodiac, kartu ucapan, kartu, kartu lebaran">
      <meta property="fb:admins" content="1048538409">
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content="166048096750307">

       <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
      <link href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/">
      <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="KapanLagi.com Atom Feed" href="/feed/entertainment.xml">
      <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kapanlagi.com/">   
      <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.kapanlagi.com/">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png"> 
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdns.klimg.com/kapanlagi.com/v5/i/channel/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png">
      <title>Kalau Bukan Sekarang, Kapan Lagi? - KapanLagi.com</title>
  ```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB, it seems to be there is a problem with selenium 2.53, and yes it is working with selenium 3. But i still have a doubt why selenium 2.53 is not giving expected source code with only this website. Because, i tested the other websites like FB, gmail etc.. they worked perfect with selenium 2.53