# Making Webpage headless is causing issue with finding WebElement through Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, headless-browser

I had to make chrome browser headless after which when I try to see the html code by executing below lines

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
ldriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
String stored_Text = ldriver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(stored_Text);
```

Output is:

> `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Because of which when I write xpath after making the page headless I'm getting **no such element exception**

Is there a way for me to circumvent this problem. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Before invoking [`getPageSource()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081962/7429447) ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) for any of the static and ***visible*** element on the page.

---

### An example

As an example to extract the *page_source* of *Google Home Page* you need to wait for the *Search Box* to be ***visible*** as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
ldriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
ldriver.get("https://www.google.com/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("q")));
String stored_Text = ldriver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(stored_Text);
```

Comment: I have introduced the wait but it made no difference

Comment: another thing I noticed is url = driver.getCurrentUrl(); is giving output as data:. I think it is opening another browser in the background.

Comment: Using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) is the ideal approach in these cases. However for individual websites there may be still issues with Selenium being detected as a bot. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: is there a possibility for you to look into this issue. Please...

Comment: With the given info, it would be difficult to proceed further and suggest anything canonical as there can be several factors at play.